# How to add tooltip to datatable header in vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

In older version on vuetify you could access headerCell slot and easily add tooltips - see https://codepen.io/nueko/pen/dZoXeZ

In the latest version you have named slots, so you need to know header name before

```
<template v-slot:header.givenname="{ header }">
```

Is there a way to add a tooltip to all headers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this.

**Option 1: Customizing whole table row**

If you need to customize whole row element inside table heading this might be useful. Even though I would not recommend to follow this way if you don't want to loose sorting functionality which exist by default in v-data-table.

**Example:**

```
<template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="h in headers">
        <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <span v-on="on">{{h.text}}</span>
        </template>
        <span>{{h.text}}</span>
      </v-tooltip>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</template>
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/onelly/pen/QWWmpZN

**Option 2: Customizing each heading without losing sorting functionality**

I guess this is more like what you are trying to do and the replacement for the old way. You can loop `<template v-slot:header>` and use [Dynamic Slot Names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names) to accomplish this. Syntax for Dynamic slot name looks like this `<template v-slot:[dynamicSlotName]>`.

**Example:**

```
<template v-for="h in headers" v-slot:[`header.${h.value}`]="{ header }">
  <v-tooltip bottom>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
      <span v-on="on">{{h.text}}</span>
    </template>
    <span>{{h.text}}</span>
  </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/onelly/pen/ExxEmWd

Comment: thanks, second option is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is great! However, when I try and add to example here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#crud-actions it raise exception "Unexpected identifier" and I think it refers to the v-slot header syntax. A reference link to how to interpret syntax `[\`header.${h.value}\`]` in `v-slot:[\`header.${h.value}\`]="{ header }"`would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: BTW... I am using inside template: \`....\` so I think I need to escape the backticks or implement alternative?

Comment: What I came up with is escaping the backticks AND the `$` - this `<template v-for="h in headers" v-slot:[\`header.${h.value}\`]="{ header }">` becomes `<template v-for="h in headers" v-slot:[\\`header.\${h.value}\\`]="{ header }">`

Comment: Is this supposed to work with Vuetify 3 datatable? because its not working for me.

Comment: @tunafish24 the answer was for Vuetify 2

Comment: Do you know how to do this in vuetify 3?

Comment: Yes seems the header slot does not work yet with vuetify 3

Comment: I take that back @tunafish24 https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/headers/#headers-slot this link seems solid

Comment: For anyone else looking for Vuetify 3 answer, its here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77084927/934257