# How to add tooltip to datatable header in vuetify 3?

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, vuetify-datatable

How can I add I tooltip to Vuetify 3 datatable header without having to re-implement sort functionality?

There was an answer to similar question few years ago but its for Vuetify 2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58718975/934257

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works the same as in the linked answer, except that the [`header.${string}`](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-header.%3Cname%3E) slot is called [`column.${string}`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-%5B%60column.%7Bstring%7D%60%5D) now, and the tooltip's [`activator`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#slots-activator) slot now gets a `props` value instead of `on`:

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers" 
  :items="items"
>
  <template
    v-for="h in headers" 
    v-slot:[`column.${h.key}`]="{ column }"
  >
    <v-tooltip>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <span v-bind="props">{{ h.title }}</span>
      </template>
      <span>{{ h.title }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.4.0, vuetify changed the name of the slot header back to  `header.${string}` like

```
v-slot:[`header.${h.key}`]="{ column }"
```

Took me a will to figure out why the solution is not working in my environment :)